# GetWindow(GetForegroundWindow() fails

Tags: c++, winapi

So far I tried to use `GetWindow` using `GetForegroundWindow` and this always returns NULL. when I use The `GetLastError` I have a msg saying 1400, Invalid windows Handle.

When I first debug I have `Null` as I said befor, but when I redo the execution I have a valid handle and all work fine.

What could be the problem.

```
static int CheckZOrder2Windows(HWND FirstWindow, HWND SecondWindow)
{
    int zOrderWnd1 = -1, zOrderWnd2 =-1;
    HWND tempHwnd = GetWindow(GetForegroundWindow(), GW_HWNDFIRST);
    if (!tempHwnd)
         ErrorExit(TEXT(""));
    DWORD dwFGThread1      = GetWindowThreadProcessId(FirstWindow, NULL);
    DWORD dwFGThread2      = GetWindowThreadProcessId(SecondWindow, NULL);

    int currentOrder = 0;
    DWORD dwFGThread = 0;
    while(tempHwnd)
    {
        ++currentOrder;
        if(IsWindowVisible(tempHwnd))
        {
            dwFGThread      = GetWindowThreadProcessId(tempHwnd, NULL);
            if (dwFGThread == dwFGThread1)
                zOrderWnd1 = currentOrder;

            else if (dwFGThread == dwFGThread2)
                zOrderWnd2 = currentOrder;              
        }
        tempHwnd=GetWindow(tempHwnd,GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
    if ((zOrderWnd1 == -1) || (zOrderWnd2 == -1))
        return 0;

    return (zOrderWnd1 - zOrderWnd2);
}
```

Comment: Getting NULL is possible, you have to deal with it.  Quoting: "The foreground window can be NULL in certain circumstances, such as when a window is losing activation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetForegroundWindow` is allowed to return NULL and you never check for that.

MSDN also says:

> The Enum[Child]Windows function is more reliable than calling GetWindow in a loop. An application that calls GetWindow to perform this task risks being caught in an infinite loop or referencing a handle to a window that has been destroyed.